# Show special characters in Unix while using 'less' Command

Tags: linux, unix, command

I would like to know how to view special characters while using 'less' command.  For instance I want to see the non-printable characters with a special notation.  For instance in 'vi' editor I use "set list on" to see the line termination characters represented by dollar '$' character.  Similarly I would want to do this using 'less' command.

I referred Unix less manual, but to no avail.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

less will look in its environment to see if there is a variable named LESS

You can set LESS in one of your ~/.profile (.bash_rc, etc, etc) and then anytime you run `less` from the comand line, it will find the LESS.

Try adding this

```
export LESS="-CQaix4"
```

This is the setup I use, there are some behaviors embedded in that may confuse you, so you can find out about what all of these mean from the help function in `less`, just tap the 'h' key and nose around, or run `less --help`.

**Edit:**

I looked at the help, and noticed there is also an `-r` option

```
-r  -R  ....  --raw-control-chars  --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
                Output "raw" control characters.
```

I agree that `cat` may be the most exact match to your stated needs.

```
cat -vet file | less
```

Will add '$' at end of each line and convert tab char to visual '^I'.

```
cat --help
   (edited)
    -e                       equivalent to -vE
    -E, --show-ends          display $ at end of each line
    -t                       equivalent to -vT
    -T, --show-tabs          display TAB characters as ^I
    -v, --show-nonprinting   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: 'cat' information helpful.  Unexplained LESS options a lot less helpful.  This would be a better answer if you removed them, since I don't think they're relevant to the question.

Comment: Where can I read more about ^ and M- notation? I know that when I type CTRL+C in the CLI that I get ^C, but I have no clue what ^M is.

Comment: Hmm, I had expected `man ascii` to natively carry that information, but had to look at http://man-ascii.com/ and click the button in the bottom row for Name vs Character to get the ^M versions to appear in the table. I think the origins of that version are in ancient unix documentation, or even predate Unix, as a many of the control chars to to control teletype machines. (never saw one myself ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: @MelvinRoest : forgot to flag my answer above to you. AND see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character for the history of Control Chars. Good luck.

Answer (score 61):

You can do that with cat and that pipe the output to less:

```
cat -e yourFile | less
```

This excerpt from [`man cat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) explains what `-e` means:

```
   -e     equivalent to -vE

   -E, --show-ends
          display $ at end of each line

   -v, --show-nonprinting
          use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

Comment: ... or `cat -eT yourfile | less` if you want to see tab characters.

Comment: I had problems with the capital T, if someone has the same problem just use ``cat -et yourfile | less`` and it should work

Answer (score 18):

For `less` use `-u` to display carriage returns (`^M`) and backspaces (`^H`), or `-U` to show the previous and tabs (`^I`) for example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "foo\bbar\tbaz\r\n"}' | less -U 
foo^Hbar^Ibaz^M

(END)
```

Without the `-U` switch the output would be:

```
fobar   baz

(END)
```

See `man less` for more exact description of the features.

Answer (score 4):

In the same spirit as https://stackoverflow.com/a/6943976/7154924:

**`cat -A`**

```
-A, --show-all
       equivalent to -vET
-v, --show-nonprinting
       use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
-E, --show-ends
       display $ at end of each line
-T, --show-tabs
       display TAB characters as ^I
```

Alternatively, or at the same time, you can pipe to `tr` to substitute arbitrary characters to the desired ones for display, before piping to a pager like `less` if desired.

Comment: I like piping to tr with these arguments to just output a dot for unprintable, because sometimes I need things to align in fixed-width fields: `tr -c '[:print:]\r\n' '.'`

Answer (score 1):

All special, nonprintable characters are displayed using ^ notation in less. However, line feed is actually printable (just make a new line), so not considered special, so you'll have problems replacing it. If you just want to see line endings, the easiest way might be

```
sed -e 's/$/$/' | less
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, sometimes you already have `less` open, and you can't use `cat` on it.  For example,  you did a `| less`, and you can't just reopen a file, as that's actually a stream.

If all you need is to identify end of line, one easy way is to search for the last character on the line: `/.$`.  The search will highlight the last character, even if it is a blank, making it easy to identify it.

That will only help with the end of line case.  If you need other special characters, you can use the `cat -vet` solution above with marks and pipe:

- mark the top of the text you're interested in: `ma`
- go to the bottom of the text you're interested in and mark it, as well: `mb`
- go back to the mark *a*: `'a`
- pipe from *a* to *b* through `cat -vet` and view the result in another less command: `|bcat -vet | less`

This will open another `less` process, which shows the result of running `cat -vet` on the text that lies between marks *a* and *b*.

If you want the whole thing, instead, do `g|$cat -vet | less`, to go to the first line and filter all lines through `cat`.

The advantage of this method over `less` options is that it does not mess with the output you see on the screen.

One would think that eight years after this question was originally posted, `less` would have that feature...  But I can't even see a feature request for it on https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues