# key logging in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I am a newbie to unix scripting, I want to do following and I have little clue how to proceed.

I want to log the input and output of certain set of commands, given on the terminal, to a trace file. I should be able to switch it on and off.

E.g.

```
switch trace on

user:echo Hello World

user:Hello World

switch trace off
```

Then the trace log file, e.g. trace.log, it's content should be

```
echo Hello World

Hello World
```

One thing that I can think to do is to use `set -x`, redirecting its output to some file, but couldn't find a way to do that. I did `man set`, or `man -x` but I found no entry. Maybe I am being too naive, but some guidance will be very helpful.
I am using bash shell.

Comment: Check out the command `script`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `script`(1), "make typescript of terminal session".  To start a new transcript in file xyz:  `script xyz`.  To add on to an existing transcript in file xyz:  `script -a xyz`.

There will be a few overhead lines, like `Script started on ...` and `Script done on ...` which you could use awk or sed to filter out on printout.  The -t switch allows a realtime playback.

I think there might have been a recent question regarding how to display a transcript in `less`, and although I can't find it, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943928/show-special-characters-in-unix-while-using-less-command) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943928/show-special-characters-in-unix-while-using-less-command) address some of the same issues of viewing a file that contains control characters.  (Captured transcripts often contain ANSI control sequences and usually contain Returns as well as Linefeeds.)

**Update 1** A Perl program [script-declutter](http://jdimpson.livejournal.com/7040.html) is available to remove special characters from script logs.
The program is about 45 lines of code found near the middle of the link.  Save those lines of code in a file called `script-declutter`, in a subdirectory that's on your PATH (for example, `$HOME/bin` if that's on your search path, else (eg) `/usr/local/bin`) and make the file executable.  After that, a command like

```
    script-declutter typescript > out
```

will remove most special characters from file `typescript`,
while directing the result to file `out`.

Comment: Thanks! Just another naive question, why couldn't i find man entry for -x or +x

Comment: Lack of persistence? :)   After you enter `man set` (or `man builtins` or `man` for any of the bash built-in commands) search for `xtrace` (remember that `set -o xtrace` is synonomous with `set -x`) and then look about 20 lines farther along for `set -x` docs.  Note that `set -x` turns on echoing of commands, which is useful for script debugging but doesn't affect command output or recording.

Comment: My bash doesn't have man entry for set or xtrace, and yet set -x works...?

Comment: Oh.  You may need to install a documentation package on your system for `man builtins` to work.  Otherwise, see [man page online](http://cs.potsdam.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?bash-builtins+7) or see [bash guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html).

Comment: I added an update with a link to a Perl program called script-declutter.