# Git tags are displayed but I can't delete one of them

Tags: git, git-tag

There it is:

[image]

I'm displaying my tags with `git tag`

However can't delete one of them which is the last tag in my repo and I want to recreate it with latest commits.

It says:

error: tag ... not found.

I see it's there in the list but not found when I try to delete it. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the single quotes are needed here:

```
git tag -d -- Retrofit2_Hatakontrolu
```

Note the use of [the double hyphen syntax '--'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309) in order to separate the command from its parameters.

Also, c[heck for the presence of special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947297/6309) in the tag name, in a Linux (Git) bash.

```
export LESS="-CQaix4r"
git tag|less
```

In the off-chance the single quotes are part of the tag name, try:

```
git tag -d -- 'Retrofit2_Hatakontrolu'
# or (escaping single quotes):
git tag -d -- \'Retrofit2_Hatakontrolu\'
```

Comment: Nope, same error with the double hyphen. Also, no special character.

Comment: @FigenGüngör Those single quotes don't show in my own git bash (Windows 10, Git 2.10.2). What version of Git are you using, on which OS?

Comment: git version 2.9.0.windows.1, Windows 10

Comment: @FigenGüngör Would the issue persists with the latest Git for Windows? https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.10.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.10.2-64-bit.7z.exe

Comment: The interesting thing is that now when I add a new tag, I don't see those single quotes, either. I'll try the latest version.

Comment: @FigenGüngör if the single quotes are part of the tag, try `git tag -d -- git tag -d -- 'Retrofit2_Hatakontrolu'` or escaping the single quotes: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yes! =) That escaping single quotes worked like a charm.  Thank you very much, @VonC.

Answer (score 1):

I just also had some nightmare with deleting a git tag that bitbucket ci pipeline created.

The name was

```
master-release-"1.0.1"-build-15
```

and by accident contained quotes.

For some reason bitbucket git accepted special characters in tag name when executing

```
readonly VERSION="$(jq '.version' version.json)"
git tag -a master-release-${VERSION}-build-15 -m "some info"
```

> And yes, I know where was the problem. I forgot to take raw output
>   from jq ,)

**Things that did not work for me.**

Local:

```
git tag -d master-release-"1.0.1"-build-15
git tag -d -- master-release-"1.0.1"-build-15
git tag -d 'master-release-"1.0.1"-build-15'
git tag -d -- 'master-release-"1.0.1"-build-15'
git tag -d "master-release-\"1.0.1\"-build-15"
git tag -d -- "master-release-\"1.0.1\"-build-15"
```

Remote:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/[and different options]
```

**Solution that worked for me.**

Local:

Edited file

```
/.git/packed-refs
```

and manualy removed two lines (tags have two lines one under the other)

```
f7e37ce5c22d2bf72b8962a93444b45277cab8fd refs/tags/master-release-"1.0.1"-build-15
^d7e57222e548949a74c84af48a0fac6779425e72
```

and localy that was just gone :)

Remote:

```
VARIABLE="\"1.0.1\""
git push origin :refs/tags/master-release-${VARIABLE}-build-15
```

Good luck.